# KD Tree insertion

Tags: c++

```
//inserts a node into the KD tree
void KDTree::insert(KDNode *point){
//If there is nothing to insert
if (point == NULL) return; 

//If the root points to nothing
if (root == NULL){
    root = point; 
    root->left = NULL; 
    root->right = NULL;
    return; 
}

insertKD(point, root); 
}

//helper function to facilitate recursion 
void KDTree::insertKD(KDNode *point, KDNode *r){
//If the point is already in the tree, don't store it
if (point->coordinates.getX() == r->coordinates.getX() && point->coordinates.getY() == r->coordinates.getY()){
    return;
} 

//save key value of parent
int key = r->key; 

//when the key is 0, we compare x-values
if (key == 0){
    //if the x-value of the point is less than the parent's store it at the left
    if (point->coordinates.getX() < r->coordinates.getX()){
        if (r->left == NULL){
            r->left = point;
            //set key to 1 since its parent has key 0
            point->key = 1; 
            return; 
        }
        else insertKD(point, r->left);
    }

    //if the x-value of the point is more than or equal the parent's store it at the right
    if (point->coordinates.getX() >= r->coordinates.getX()){
        if (r->right == NULL){
            r->right = point; 
            //set key to 1 since its parent has key 0
            point->key = 1; 
            return; 
        }
        else insertKD(point, r->right);
    }
}

//when the key is 1, we compare y-values 
if (key == 1){
    //if the y-value of the point is less than the parent's store it at the left
    if (point->coordinates.getY() < r->coordinates.getY()){
        if (r->left == NULL){
            r->left = point; 
            //set key to 0 since its parent has key 1
            point->key = 0;
            return; 
        }
        else insertKD(point, r->left);
    }

    //if the y-value of the point is more than or equal the parent's store it at the right
    if (point->coordinates.getY() >= r->coordinates.getY()){
        if (r->right == NULL){
            r->right = point; 
            //set key to 0 since its parent has key 1
            point->key = 0;
            return; 
        }
        else insertKD(point, r->right);
    }
}  
}
```

When I was testing whether the tree worked I realized that its not inserting the elements properly (it only inserts the first). I have a for loop that allocates memory for a class type and then uses this function. I went into debugging mode to see where the pointers are pointing to. The first time (i = 0) the new object I allocate points to a memory value(expected), then on the next loop (i = 1), root points to the same memory value (also expected), but when i call the function again to insert, on the third loop the value of root->left or root->right doesn't point to anything (it just said 0x0, my constructor initialized them to NULL). What's wrong with the code I did it manually and it seemed to work logically?

Comment: New info: I stepped into the function insertKD(.....), and it skips both if statements (whether x is greater or less than the parent) the input I'm getting is somehow wrong.

Comment: Add more code, specifically, your KDNode class definition and your test statements (i.e. what exactly you inserting).